How to set up SLURM with GPU for for Single-Node usage
I have a relatively powerful machine which I use to run simulations. I am trying to set up SLURM to make running programs easier.
slurm.conf:
NodeName=localhost Name=gpu type=gefore_rtx_3090 File=/dev/nvidia0
NodeName=localhost Name=mps count=200 File=/dev/nvidia0

gres.conf
ClusterName=localcluster
SlurmctldHost=beast
MpiDefault=none
ProctrackType=proctrack/linuxproc
ReturnToService=2
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmd
SlurmUser=slurm
StateSaveLocation=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmctld
SwitchType=switch/none
TaskPlugin=task/none
#
# TIMERS
InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
MinJobAge=300
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=300
Waittime=0
# SCHEDULING
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/cons_tres
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
#
#AccountingStoragePort=
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
SlurmctldDebug=info
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=info
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log
#
# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=localhost CPUs=80 Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=20 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=193044 Gres=gpu:,mps:200 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=LocalQ Nodes=ALL Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP

## GRES
GresTypes=gpu,mps
DebugFlags=CPU_Bind,gres

However, when I try to run:
sudo service slurmctld restart && sudo service slurmd restart

I get the following error:

I am not sure what the problem is. The documentation uses the same key: https://slurm.schedmd.com/gres.html
After resolving some further issues, It seems to be working.

Did you mix up the content of slurm.conf and gres.conf? These configuration files expect different sets of keywords and serve distinct purposes in Slurm configuration.

From the error message, and from the titles in the post, the contents of slurm.conf and gres.conf have been exchanged. Rename them and try again?

I chaged the content of the files and it has resolved the original error(s). Thank you.  I got some new ones, I am trying to resolve those now.
